# Communication with sensor KMX63 in I2C

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c, arduino-mini

I trying to use a new sensor the KMX63 with a Arduino Uno board, my sensor is on a evaluation board made by kionix.
For the connexion il linked as follows:

| Pin Uno | Pin evaluation board |
| A5 | 5 |
| A4 | 7 |
| 3.3 | 1 |
| GND | 8 |

Here the schematic of the evaluation board:
[image: eval board schematic]

I found a technical note from the constructor that advice to do some steps after the power up of the sensor to insure it's well functioning I wrote a code following it:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include "KMX62.h"


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  Serial.println(F("Starting"));

  byte error=7;
  byte id=0;
  byte command=0;
  delay(60);
  Wire.beginTransmission(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2);
  Wire.write(0x7F);
  Serial.println(F("Write 0x7F"));
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Serial.println(F("Write 0x00"));
  delay(100);
  error=Wire.endTransmission();
  Serial.print(F("retour 1 : "));
  Serial.println(error);
  if( error==0 ){
    Wire.beginTransmission(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2);
    Wire.write(CNTL2);
    Wire.write(0x00);
    error=Wire.endTransmission();
    if( error==0 ){
      Wire.beginTransmission(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2);
      Wire.write(CNTL1);
      Wire.write(0x80);
      error=Wire.endTransmission();
      if(error==0){
        delay(5);
        Wire.beginTransmission(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2);
        Wire.write(WHO_AM_I);
        Wire.endTransmission(false);
        Wire.requestFrom(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2,1);
        id=Wire.read();
        error=Wire.endTransmission();
        if(id==0x18||id==0x2D){
          Wire.beginTransmission(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2);
          Wire.write(COTR);
          Wire.endTransmission(false);
          Wire.requestFrom(KMX62_I2C_ADD_2,1);
          command=Wire.read();
          error=Wire.endTransmission();
          if(command==0x55){
            Serial.println(F("device ok"));
          }else{
            Serial.println(F("Issue with the sensor step e : need to be rebooted"));
          }
        }else{
          Serial.println(F("Issue with the sensor step d id=wrong : need to be rebooted"));
        }
      }else{
        if(error==2||error==3){
        Serial.println(F("Issue with the sensor step c : need to be rebooted"));
        }
      }
    }else{
      if(error==2||error==3){
        Serial.println(F("Issue with the sensor step b : need to be rebooted"));
      }
    }
  }
}

void loop(){

}
```

but i have an issue the steps , the program seem to freeze when i try to write into the register 0x7F.
I don't get any trace that i should have after the wire.endtransmission().
Here the trace i obtain :

```cpp
09:56:35.477 -> Starting
09:56:35.511 -> Write 0x7F
09:56:35.511 -> Write 0x00
```

i have use the I2C scanner to check if the sensor appear, i had to modify the scanner to add a delay before Wire.beginTransmission and the Wire.endTransmission to avoid the scanner to be freeze too at the first address tried. After the modification i did saw the sensor at the address it was mean to be.
here the trace for the I2C scanner :

```cpp
Scanning...
I2C device found at address 0x0F  !
done
```

Anyone have an idea of why i can't write anything to my sensor without making my program freeze indefinitely each time ?

PS : After the advice of chrisl i rerunned all my programs on a arduino mini pro on 3.3V / 8Mhz and got the same result.

Comment: Can you explain the "delay(100)" before "Wire.endTransmission()"? You know that the "endTransmission" is actually the start of transmission.

Comment: Does the evaluation board run on 3.3V?

Comment: i didn't had understood that the transmission started only after the endTransmission. I have added the delay() because into the I2C scanner i had to add a delay(100) between the beginTransmission and endTransmission or the scanner was blocking at the address tryed

Comment: @chrisl i tryed with the both alimentation pin of the Uno the 3.3 and the 5V and got the same result

Comment: But the Uno will try to raise SDA and SCL to 5V, while the evaluation board would only raise it to 3.3V. So there will be a cross current. If you want to connect a 5V and a 3.3V device via I2C, you definitely need a level shifter.

Comment: And does that mean, that you power the evaluation board over the 3.3V pin of the Uno? You have to check, how much current the board needs. It might be too much for the 3.3V regulator on the Uno. Please check these things first and don't connect 5V to a 3.3V device, unless you really know, that it can tolerate that. You might destroy the device otherwise.

Comment: yes i powered the evaluation board with the 3.3V of the UNO, i juste do a supplement test with a mini pro 3.3V 8MHZ and i obtain the same result my program freeze but the scanner I2C does find the sensor I2C address : 0x0F

Comment: BW: What register is 0x7F? Could you add a link to the product spec you are using? The one I found did not have this register. This might be the issue. Could it be register 0x7A that you mean?

Comment: http://kionixfs.kionix.com/en/document/TN005-Power-On-Procedure.pdf

This is the technical note concerning the power on procedure for the sensor. It did looked strange for me when i read the address register 0x7F but i guessed it may be a register that we normally don't need to touch

Comment: Did you try the startup sequence from this https://github.com/ROHMUSDC/ROHM_SensorPlatform_Multi-Sensor-Shield/blob/master/Platform%20Code/Arduino_UNO_FirmwareExample/ROHM_SENSORSHLD1-EVK-101_10-20-2016/ROHM_SENSORSHLD1-EVK-101_TerminalDemo_11-10-2016/ROHM_SENSORSHLD1-EVK-101_TerminalDemo_11-10-2016.ino?

Comment: @MikaelPatel I didn't know that i try this startup sequence using the wire library but got the same result, programe seem locked with the first writing. Does the issue can come from the wire library ?

Comment: There are several hardware issues here before assuming it is software.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found where the problem was, i had made a error on the reading of the schematic of the evaluation board. I thought that the pin J1-9 was already wired in intern but it was wrong. I wired it to the VCC output of my board and it work perfectly now.